# Tokenizer for indexing source code

Tags: solr, lucene, tokenize

Lets say you want to create a search engine for a site like github or stackoverflow, where the majority of the textual content is actually source code. What would be a good Lucene tokenizer for dealing with documents of this type?

Comment: Generally, source code uses whitespace and punctuation to separate things, so I would think simply using `StandardAnalyzer` would probably work pretty well, or possibly a custom analyzer like `StandardAnalyzer` but without the `LowercaseFilter`, depending on your needs.  Is there some particular feature you are looking for, as far as how you would like code to be tokenized?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for : http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/02/18/indexing-stackoverflow-in-solr/ .  This covers all the steps and more.